# angular 5 - show product detail in div with effect when mouse hover on product

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular5

I have for loop to show all my product in page .. now I want when the user hovers on the product its related detail show in div with effect i did like this but I think it's not correct way also opacity not work in my code.

... my purpose is the detail(in my code div with calas `"c-reveal"`) should be shown with effect when mouse enter on product and detail will disappear when user leave detail or parent

```
  <ul class="home-product">
      <li *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index " [attr.data-index]="i" (mouseenter)="show($event)"
          (mouseleave)="leavep($event)">

        <div class="card product-card">

          <div class="card-content">
           {{ product.title }}
          </div>


          <div class="c-reveal" (mouseleave)="leave($event)">
            this will show when parent hoverd
          </div>

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

css:

```
.c-reveal {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-left: 247px;
  bottom: 155px;
  width: 225px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

.show{
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;

}
```

component.ts:

```
  show(e) {

    let card = e.srcElement.children[0].children[2];
    card.classList.add('show');


  }

  leavep(e) {
    console.log(e);
    let card = e.srcElement.children[0].children[2];
    card.classList.remove('show');
  }

  leave(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    target.classList.remove('show');
  }
```

Comment: You should use angular's states animations for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly in css:

put a class on your product div like `product`

```
<li *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index " [attr.data-index]="i" class="product">
```

and then just do

```
.product:hover .c-reveal { display: block; opacity: 1 }
```

Comment: i think this will display all detail div for all products when i hover frist product

Comment: No, because the :hover will be effective only on the product you will hover =)

Answer (score 0):

I've created a directive that adds css class to another html element on hover. Check this out:

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[hover]',
})
export class HoverDirective  {
  @Input() el: HTMLElement;
  @Input() activeClass: string;

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseenter() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el, this.activeClass);
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseleave() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.el, this.activeClass);
  }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
}
```

Usage

```
<p hover activeClass="active" [el]="anotherEl">
  Hover over me to add class to another element
</p>

<div #anotherEl>Another element</div>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hover-directive)

Comment: by this way when i hover my first product. all product detail div will apear